# VBA check length of cell value in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have codes that populate cells in column A (A7:A446) of a main sheet. These values are listed in a different sheet (Sheet3) and the user double-clicks on a code they want to populate the active cell back on the main sheet. These codes have descriptions (Column E, E7:E446)  that go with them and the codes themselves are supposed to be 21 characters long. Currently, the description column (Column E) has a IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP...)) formula to pull the account descriptions associated with the account code being double-clicked in Sheet3. I want to write in VBA, a sub that checks if the codes in column A are 21 characters long. If the account codes are not 21 characters long, I want the description, and only the description, to be "N/A" to indicate that the code is invalid. In addition, if the code in column A does not equal any of the account codes listed in Sheet3, I would like the same action, the description in column E to be "N/A, and the only the description.

I'm aware I can probably do this with a formula or function inside the description column itself but in an attempt to better familiarize myself with VBA, I'd like to do it this way. I've tried to write a sub to do this but it has not been working. I think I have set some of the variable to incorrect datatypes but I'm not entirely sure. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
  Sub acctCodeVarification()

acctCode = Sheet2.Range("C7:C446").Value
acctDesc = Sheet2.Range("E7:E446").Text

For Each c In Range("C7:C446").Cells
    If Len(c) <> 21 Then
    c.acctDesc = "N/A"
    If c <> Sheet3.Range("A1:A20681").Value Then
    c.acctDesc = "N/A"

    End If
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for editing your original post.  I see that you want only the description, column E, updated.  You have stated you already have a formula in that column.  Does that formula not already perform the operation of going to "N/A" when an account code is invalid?  And because you want the VBA code to update column E, it will override the formula.  VBA can replace or update the formula instead of using a straight value if preferred.  Based on your provided code though, you want to replace the formula in column E with the text value "N/A", correct?  Note that will remove the formula

Comment: Do you want the code to perform the VLOOKUP if the account code is validated and put in the value of its description?

Comment: @tigeravatar I didn't realize the VBA code would overwrite my current formula in column E. Yes, the code can perform the VLOOKUP, I don't really have a preference. If the VBA code can do that, that would be a good chance for me to familiarize myself with that functionality within VBA.

Comment: The current formula if my column E looks like this `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C8,acct_codes!$A$2:$B$20681,2,FALSE)), " ",VLOOKUP(C8,acct_codes!$A$2:$B$20681,2,FALSE))` I tried to get all the functionality I want with the formula but it doesn't look right and is super long `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C9,acct_codes!$A$2:$B$20681,2,FALSE)), " ",VLOOKUP(C9,acct_codes!$A$2:$B$20681,2,FALSE)) & IF(C9 = " ", "", "") & IF(C9 <> acct_codes!$A$2:$A$20681, "N/A", VLOOKUP(C9,acct_codes!$A$2:$B$20681,2,FALSE)) & IF(LEN(C9) <>21, "N/A", VLOOKUP(C9,acct_codes!$A$2:$B$20681,2,FALSE))`

Comment: Would you prefer a formula solution instead of VBA?

Comment: @tigeravatar Yes, I would. At first I wanted VBA so I could study it and learn VBA a bit more, but since I already have part of the formula, I guess finishing the functionality I wanted with a formula would suffice, as well.

Comment: Give this formula a try: `=IF(AND(LEN(C8)=21,COUNTIF(acct_codes!$A:$A,C8)>0),VLOOKUP(C8,acct_codes!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"N/A")`

Comment: @tigeravatar Thanks so much for that. When I copy/paste that formula I get an error message stating "There's a problem with this formula" Not sure why. I thought it could be the parenthesis but that's not it

Comment: hmm... it works for me.  Try manually typing it in and manually selecting the ranges

Comment: @tigeravatar I manually entered the formula and that worked. Thank you so much! You were a great help

Comment: @tigeravatar I would like one small additional functionality within this formula, if possible. When there is no account code in the C column, the description column reads, "N/A". How could I get the description column to be blank until an invalid account code is entered in the description cell? Thanks again!

Comment: =IF(C8="","",*formula*)

Comment: @tigeravatar by `formula` do you mean the VLOOKUP formula?

Comment: I was mostly just trying to avoid typing the whole thing again, heh.  It would look like this: `=IF(C8="","",IF(AND(LEN(C8)=21,COUNTIF(acct_codes!$A:$A,C8)>0),VLOOKUP(C‌​8,acct_codes!$A:$B,2‌​,FALSE),"N/A"))`

Comment: @tigeravatar okay, great! That worked. Sorry you had to type it out but I sincerely appreciate you're help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your description and your provided code don't match each other which raises some questions, but here are the assumptions I've made based on your provided code:

- Your "Main" sheet is Sheet2
- Your "Verify" sheet is Sheet3
- Account codes that are being verified are in the Main sheet, column C, starting at cell C7
- Descriptions (which are not checked or verified at all) are in the Main sheet, column E, starting at cell E7
- The list of actual account codes to verify against are in the Verify sheet, column A
- If the account code being checked is NOT exactly 21 characters, set that cell (column C in Main sheet) and its description to "N/A"
- If the account code IS 21 characters, but is NOT found in the verify list, set only the description to "N/A"

Following that logic, this code should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim wsVerify As Worksheet
    Dim rAcctCodes As Range
    Dim rAcctCell As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsMain = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")    'Change to actual name of worksheet
    Set wsVerify = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")  'Change to actual name of worksheet
    Set rAcctCodes = wsMain.Range("C7", wsMain.Cells(wsMain.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))

    For Each rAcctCell In rAcctCodes.Cells
        If Len(rAcctCell.Value) <> 21 Then rAcctCell.Value = "N/A"
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsVerify.Columns("A"), rAcctCell.Value) = 0 Then wsMain.Cells(rAcctCell.Row, "E").Value = "N/A"
    Next rAcctCell

End Sub
```

Comment: If a IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP...)) formula is already in the cells in column E to pull valid account descriptions, would that not allow or affect the VBA code having the description be "N/A"?

Comment: @anve Using a formula in column E to result in an "N/A" value is fine, but you specifically stated the point of this exercise is to practice VBA?  If you'd rather only use a formula for column E, simply remove the second `If` line in the loop

Comment: @anve If the logic I have made assumptions about based on your provided code and description is incorrect, instead of editing my answer please edit your original post to make it clearer.

Comment: I do want the formula to pull the account descriptions and that's it. I DO want the vba code to verify the account code itself. My question is, will having the IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP...)) already in column E cells affect the vba code at all?

Comment: @anve No, it will not affect the VBA code at all if the VBA code does not reference or change column E.

Answer (score 1):

Since the following variables are declared as string, they do not need a "Set" statement.  So instead of:

```
Set acctCode = Sheet2.Range("C7:C446").Value
Set acctDesc = Sheet2.Range("E7:E446").Text
```

Do this:

```
acctCode = Sheet2.Range("C7:C446").Value
acctDesc = Sheet2.Range("E7:E446").Text
```

Comment: This is just one of the problems.  There are others.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim acctCode As Range
Set acctCode = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C7:C446")

For Each c In Range("C7:C446").Cells
If Len(c.Value) <> 21 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & c.Row) = "N/A"
Else
    If Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A20681").Find(c.Value,LookIn:=xlValues).Value Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & c.Row) = "N/A"
    Else
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & c.Row) = c.Value
    End If
End If
Next c
```

Comment: If I have a IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP)) formula is column E to pull the account descriptions being double-clicked, would that affect the VBA code? Since I am trying to have the account description be "N/A" if the code doesn't equal the list of account code or if the account code isn't 21 characters long?